# How to create an unsubscribe feature in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am working on a django project, and I'm needing to add an unsubscribe feature to my emails that the server will be sending out. The way that I am managing the mailing list is through a .csv file, which when someone signs up for a service of our's, they get added to the mailing list. In the emails, I want to add an easy unsubscribe feature which would only require the user to click the link in the email, which would lead them to a page that will have a button for the user to unsubscribe from the service, which would be accomplished by removing their name from the mailing list .csv file. My question is, how do I set it up where, when the link is clicked in the email, the website will already know which user is attempting to unsubscribe?

I was attempting to follow a tutorial here [Tutorial](http://www.grokcode.com/819/one-click-unsubscribes-for-django-apps/?comments=y) but I do not have a "user profiles" set up, as it mentions. What other ways might this be accomplished? Is there a way to send the email's username to the website when the page is visited in order for me to make the unsubscription process easier?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is too broad to be answered here but you should be sending each email individually and include a uniquely identifiable information such as the email address or the user id in that unsubscribe link.

Comment: One suggestion that I was given was to create an unsubscribe link that would tail with the string '?email=youruser@domain.com', but it didn't seem to actually be accepted on the Django server.

Comment: What do you mean by not accepted? Can you post what you tried?

Comment: My code is on another machine that is disabled at my office at the moment, however, what I was attempting to do was visit the link with 'http://example.com/home/unsubscribe/?email=myuser@domain.com', and this didn't seem to do anything. I'll post what I'm doing in Django the first chance I get.